# Does antlr automatically factor top-level alternates?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, grammar

I have written the following two grammars, one grouping the arithmetic expressions (where possible) and another that doesn't:

```
grammar NoPrefix;
root: (expr ';')* EOF;

expr
    : '(' expr ')'
    | expr '*' expr
    | expr '/' expr
    | expr '+' expr
    | expr '-' expr
    | Atom
    ;

Atom: [a-z]+ | [0-9]+ | '\'' Atom '\'';
WHITESPACE: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

```
grammar YesPrefix;
root: (expr ';')* EOF;

expr
    : '(' expr ')'
    | expr ('*'|'/') expr
    | expr ('+'|'-') expr
    | Atom
    ;

Atom:[a-z]+ | [0-9]+ | '\'' Atom '\'';
WHITESPACE: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

It seems that these two have almost identical runtimes, build sizes, etc. Does antlr automatically convert the two forms of alternatives to the same output, for example:

```
expr: expr '*' expr | expr '/' expr    <==> expr: expr ('*'|'/') expr;
```

Comment: Note that those have different semantics. In the first one, `3/a*b` is `3/(a*b)` instead of `(3/a)*b`. Get your grammar right before worrying about anything else :-)

Comment: Oh, because in that example `*` and `/` (should) have the same precedence and otherwise we make `*` have a higher precedence than `/`, and so it's evaluating first, rather than equally-but-left-associative, is that correct?

Comment: If you generate a .dot graph for each grammar and look at the expr .dot file, you will see there is a slight difference between the two grammars due to the different precedence for operators. Antlr is very limited in rule refactoring. The only one I know of is for left recursion. [trgroup](https://github.com/kaby76/Domemtech.Trash/tree/main/src/trgroup) can do a grouping, which you describe, of "n" alts in a grammar, but it merges all alts in the alt list, not a selection of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. How would Antlr know that you wanted `*` and `/` to have the same binding precedence, different from `+` and `-`? You need to be explicit about that.